# Google Play Service Location API: onLocationChanged only called once

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services

I have a service which use Google Play Service API to get current location. But the onLocationChanged is always only called once when the service started, even if I use Location Spoof to cheat on a new location, which should invoke the onLocationChanged.

I am pretty sure the Location Spoof is working correctly b/c when I restart the service it did give me a fake location when the Location Spoof software is enabled. I also did set a interval and fastInterval for mLocationRequest. I also have add the  in my manifest.

I tried to use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY instead. It seems fixed if I made this change but I was not supposed to use GPS for this application since the service was designed to run 24/7.

Here's part of my code:

```
public MyService extends Service {
       //.....Other part...
       public void geolocationScanInit() {
              serviceEnableStatus = true
              mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
              mLocationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
              mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
              mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING);

              locationCallbacks = new LocationCallbacks(this, mLocationRequest);
   }
}
```

And this is the LocationCallbacks class I designed

```
public class LocationCallbacks implements LocationListener, GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private final String TAG = "LocationService";

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;
    private MyService mService;

    public LocationCallbacks(MyService ms, 
        LocationRequest locReq) {
        mService = ms;
        mLocationRequest = locReq;
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(mService, this, this);
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

    public void startLocationUpdate() {
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, LocationCallbacks.this);
    }

    public void stopLocationUpdate() {
        if (mLocationClient != null && mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
            mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onConnected");
        startLocationUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mService.recievedLocationChanged(new GlobalLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    }

}
```

I have search for stackOverflow But does not find any similar question.
Although it seems like most of the application of Google Play Service incorporate the Service and LocationCallbacks together, which does not make sense in my application because getting the current location is only one of the functionality (actually the least important one) in my service. And I doubt if that is going to be a problem.

Thanks!

========================================================

Update:

I think I may have some clue to this question.

I found this:
[onLocationChanged just called once using network provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190540/onlocationchanged-just-called-once-using-network-provider)
Although it is different API but there could be connection.
If that's true then it seems like its going to be hard to do what I want.

Besides, through my testing, I found that the service is actually calling onLocationChanged. It is just update it at a very low frequency which does not follow the LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL and FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING I set (I set it to be 8000ms and 2000ms respectively). Currently it updates once in 10+ minutes.

But I still don't know a solution to achieve what I want. Any suggestion?

Would it be a good idea if I manually request location using a Timer or something similar?

Answer (score 4):

I too went through the same issue, and luckily the below worked for me. Took 4 hours of trial and run method.

It seems that the `locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, this);` needs a determining factor as when to fetch updates for location changes.

This factors come from the LocationRequest object passed to the LocationClient.

Try combining your already specified facotrs with `setSmallestDisplacement(float meters)` which takes the minimum distance in meters from your last-location in order to trigger `onLocationChanged(Location loc)`.

Your `LocationRequest` will now look like this,

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
mLocationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING);
mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10); //10 meters
```

Please let know if this does the trick for you too. :)